# Domino web app Error 500 HTTP Web Server: Corrupt Data Exception

Tags: lotus-domino

I have a Domino App that runs on the web as well as in the lotus notes client.  I can open and save my main form in the LN client without issues and i can open it in the browser as well.  When i try to save it in the browser, i get the "Error 500 HTTP Web Server: Corrupt Data Exception" page displayed.  I made a copy of the form, and started removing all of the fields on the original one field at a time and still got the error page.  I copied an identical form from my test database to the production db thinking that would work but i get the error "Error 404 Entry not found in index" error page with that form.

I am at a complete loss as what to do next so i am hoping that someone here can give me a little direction.

Thanks

Comment: Is it related to this error? "The error occurs when you have multiple replicas of a database on a single Lotus Domino server."
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21198264

Answer (score 1):

Corrupt Data Exception is usually displayed if: 1 open the document in web, 2 change the designe of the form 3 try to save.

Did you removed all cache of you browser (ok this is trivially but I can't be sure you checked this)
could you check in the log.nsf what is the precise error written there (Corrupt Data.. which DB which &seq= )
did you try rebooting (or at least tell http restart) the server?

the 2nd part Entry not found in index, check if the form makes a DBlookup or what ever:
- on view in the current DB that is in test
- on another DB which design doesn't contain same design element in prod than in test

if all this doesn't help make a backup of the db and try fixup and so on.